# Combining all DLLs and resources into one EXE for Winforms programs? ILMerge seems to be on the way out?

Tags: winforms, ilmerge

It seems that merging DLLs to create a single exe is now discouraged since ILMerge does not seem to be available from Microsoft any longer.

Is this the case or is there a better way to accomplish this now? For some of our internal applications it would be very nice to have a single file to distribute rather than a directory full of DLLs.

Comment: It is [not gone](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge).  Using setup.exe as the single-file-to-deploy hasn't gone out of style either.